# Method in React component not rendering HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hello I am fairly new to React and I have having a bit of trouble I don't think I should be experiencing. I have a component that has two methods the first method is `test` and the second is the standard `render`. Check it out:

```
var Projects = React.createClass({
    test: function(){
      return(
          <h1>Why</h1>
        )
    },
    render: function(){

      return (
          <div className="postWrapper">
            <div id="projectsHeader">
              <h1>Projects</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="projectsBody">
              {this.test}
            </div>
          </div>

        )
    }
  });
```

The problem is when I am calling the `test` method using `{this.test}` within the Projects component, nothing renders. I want this method to be available within the component so I can eventually render multiple items programmatically. What am I doing wrong? Since I am using React Router I don't know how to pass children props when they are also being rendered programmatically using `{this.props.children}`, which is what I tried to do within the `MasterLayout` component but became stuck. I'll provide the rest of my code for context, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var MasterLayout = React.createClass({
  mixins: [History], 
  getInitialState: function(){
    return{
      hello: {}
    }
  },
  renderProjects: function(){
      return(
          <div>
            <h1>This better work</h1>
          </div>
          )
    },
  render: function(){
    return(
        <div id="container">
          <Navigation />
          <div id="content">
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        </div>
      )

  }
});

var Projects = React.createClass({
    test: function(){
      return(
          <h1>Why</h1>
        )
    },
    render: function(){

      return (
          <div className="postWrapper">
            <div id="projectsHeader">
              <h1>Projects</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="projectsBody">
              {this.test}
            </div>
          </div>

        )
    }
  });

  var TestPage = React.createClass({

    render: function(){
      return(
          <div className="postWrapper">
            <div id="postHeader">
              <div id="titleDate">
                <h2>This is a test blog title</h2>
                <span>1/1/2016</span>
              </div>
              <div id="testFrame">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="postBody">
              <p>...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
    }
  })


var routes = (
          <Router history={history}>
            <Route path="/" component={MasterLayout}>
              <IndexRoute component={TestPage}></IndexRoute>
              <Route path="/projects" component={Projects}></Route>
            </Route>
          </Router>
  )



ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not *calling* `test`; you're trying to output the function itself, not the result of the function. Just add some `()` after `this.test`:

```
var Projects = React.createClass({
    test: function() {
      return(
          <h1>Why</h1>
        )
    },
    render: function() {
      return (
          <div className="postWrapper">
            <div id="projectsHeader">
              <h1>Projects</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="projectsBody">
              {this.test()}
            </div>
          </div>
      )
    }
});
```

Comment: It was that easy huh? Wow. Thank you very much for the swift reply, I was under the impression I did not have to invoke the function with the `()`. I think it's time to take a break for the evening haha. Cheers.